# How to include selector value in Kendo UI Upload template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo upload component with a custom template that will include a dropdown list for each file selected. The user will select a list of files to upload and then use the dropdown lists to select the upload type for each item in the upload list.

```
<script id="fileTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <span class='k-progress'></span>
    <div class='file-wrapper'>
        <span class='file-icon #=addExtensionClass(files[0].extension)#'></span>
        <h4 class='file-heading file-name-heading'>Name: #=name#</h4>
        <h4 class='file-heading file-size-heading'>Size: #=size# bytes</h4>
        <label></label>
        <select id="uploadType" class="uploadType" name="uploadType">
            <option>Unknown</option>
            <option>Type A</option>
            <option>Type B</option>
            <option>Type C</option>
            <option>Type D</option>
        </select>
        <button type='button' class='k-upload-action'></button>
    </div>
</script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#files").kendoUpload({
        multiple: true,
        async: {
            saveUrl: '@Url.Action("Save", "DataUpload")',
            autoUpload: false
        },
        template: kendo.template($("#fileTemplate").html()),
        error: onError
    });
});

    function onError(e)
    {
        ???How do I get error information to use here???
    }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, ???)
{
    //I need to know what type was selected before I can decide what
    //processing should be done for the file. So, I assume I need another
    //Param that contains he type selected by the user.

    return Content("");
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I get access to the dropdown values set for each item from inside my controller action?
2. if the upload fails how do I get error information to use in the onError method?

Comment: You can access the errors in onError via **e.Errors**

Comment: I get e.Errors is undefined when I attempt to display the error msg.

Comment: Sorry my bad, you won't be able to get the errors directly as I mentioned.